# multiple shorten url's issue

Tags: php

i have a code to shorten multiple links but that code ( with an Optional Suffix ) the code is work from the second link only:

```
$url_to_shorten = $_POST[links];
$ownshuff       = $_POST[shuff];   
$theurls = explode("\n",$url_to_shorten);  
foreach($theurls as $urlmulti){  
shortcreate($urlmulti,$shuffss,$ownshuff);
}
```

here is an example :

my links are

```
http://www.123.com
http://www.1234.com
http://www.1235.com
```

and my Suffix is : ( Hello_Man ).

with the above code it prints

```
http://www.mysite.com/IUo
http://www.mysite.com/kOl-Hello_Man
http://www.mysite.com/Rww-Hello_Man
```

and it not print the Suffix for the first link.

the shortcreate function is :

```
function shortcreate($url_long, $Suffix, $ownshuf){
    global $db;
    $chars = $Suffix;
    while (!shortisUnique($chars)) {
        if ($ownshuf != "") {
            $chars = shortgenerate_chars() . "-" . $ownshuf;
        }
        else {
            $chars = shortgenerate_chars();
        }
    }
    $url = $url_long;
    $url = trim($url);
    $url = mysql_real_escape_string($url);
    if (!shortisThere($url)) {
        $q = "INSERT INTO `shorturls` (url, unique_chars) VALUES ('" . $url . "', '" . $chars . "')";
        //echo $q;
        $r = $db->query($q);
        if (mysql_affected_rows()):
            $q       = "SELECT * FROM `shorturls` WHERE `url`='" . $url . "'";
            $r       = $db->query($q);
            $row     = $db->fetch($r);
            $the_url = SITE_URL . "" . $row[2];

            echo "$the_url\n";

        else:
            $the_url = NULL;
            return false;
        endif;
    }
    else {
        $q       = "SELECT * FROM `shorturls` WHERE `url` = '" . $url . "'";
        $r       = mysql_query($q);
        $row     = mysql_fetch_row($r);
        $the_url = SITE_URL . "" . $row[2];

        echo "$the_url\n";

    }
}
```

i need that code to work for all the links. any help

regards

Comment: How are you shortening links when the output is longer than the input?

Comment: What does `shortcreate` do? Why are you not putting the string array keys in quotes? Why are you getting `$_POST_` on line 2?

Comment: What are `$_POST_` (with an underscore), `shortcreate()` and `$shuffss`?

Comment: How are you outputting the result to the browser?

Comment: the data comes from text area and the shortcreate() is a function to short the urls

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the problem is in the next block of code:

```
$chars = $Suffix;
while (!shortisUnique($chars)) {
    if ($ownshuf != "") {
        $chars = shortgenerate_chars() . "-" . $ownshuf;
    }
    else {
        $chars = shortgenerate_chars();
    }
}
```

You give the $chars variable the value of the suffix and you check if it's unique (guess not because it's getting into the loop) and that condition of `$ownshuf != ""` returns `false` from some reason (consider to share with us what's that parameter's value), otherwise the output of `$chars` would return a string with "-".

**REMINDER:** Share with us what's that parameter's value